# PyCharm debug mode change execution point

Tags: debugging, pycharm

I am new with PyCharm and I cannot find how to move the cursor up in debug mode. I mean that in some IDE (VisualStudio and RStudio for instance) I have been used to find out my error, re-execute the statement and keep going over the program.

I can't find how to do this in python with PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

On an ubuntu machine, the debug mode has the following types:

1. step over(F8)
2. step into(F7)
3. step out (Shift + F8)
4. step into my code (Alt + Shift + F7)

For your [reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging.html)